# Acer cant boot, I get beep code then computer restarts beeps again then restarts

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

Originally the Acer Aspire desktop would beep 3 times pause then beep 3 more times over and over again then finally start up anyway and work without a problem.

Today i had time to trouble shoot so i started up Windows Memory Diagnostic to check the RAM and told the computer to reboot. Now all of a sudden the computer will not boot. It will beep 3 times pause then 3 more beeps then it will completely shut off. Then it restarts itself and does that all over again.

I have tried disconnecting the hard drive with no luck. I have also tried each stick of RAM (i have 4 x 4GB) with no luck. Finally if I remove ALL the RAM then it will start up beep once and stay running however there is no signal to the monitor and no hard drive or processor activity.

When the RAM is in there is also no signal to the monitor so I am unable to get into BIOS or recovery of any kind. Could this be a video card problem? I have an Intel Core i7 with integrated Intel graphics card so I am unable to reseat the GPU card as there isnt one.

When the computer originally started giving me beep codes on startup once it did boot up there seemed to be nothing wrong, everything ran smoothly and I did not notice any issue untill i tried to run Windows Memory Diagnostic. Now at this point I am not able to do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given your hardware what does the error code mean?

Comment: well it depends on if you consider it 3 beeps. or 6 beeps. From what i can see most places say it is RAM, but i have tested all the RAM and it seems fine. After resetting CMOS i can now get it to boot however it still beeps 6 times.

Comment: It might be useful to get a diagnostic card, something like http://www.gizmosforgeeks.com/soyo-techaid-diagnostic-card, which would give you a lot more detail about what;s happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Cant seem to follow the link to see purchasing options for that card. Do you know if this would be a comparable card?? http://www.amazon.ca/Motherboard-Repair-Troubleshoot-Boot-Failure-Diagnostic/dp/B00AAYY08Y/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1425397001&sr=8-15&keywords=Diagnostic+Card

Comment: That looks similar.  The advantage of the Soyo one is a tethered display.  It is often hard to see the on-card display.  A tethered display lets you see it in a convenient location.  There are lots of such diagnostic cards in the marketplace.